# Power Automate - How to attach image

Tags: twilio, power-automate

I am trying to use Power Automate to send a text with an attached image.

The image is stored in onedrive, so I use "Create Share Link By Path" to create a url for the image.

If I just go directly to the link, the image is there.

On the Power Automate side, it's showing that the flow ran successfully.

If I look at my twilio log, the text send fails with error #11200 HTTP Retrieval failure. There was a failure attempting to retrieve the contents of this url.

[image]

For troubleshooting I tried texting the url to another person to see if it could be a permissions issue with onedrive.  If the link is in the body of the text, they can click on the link and view teh schedule.

But if I try to send the actual image, it won't send.

Comment: Twilio can never get the URL content as your URL is in OneDrive and private to your organization.  So this error is expected, you can only send as link not as image, unless your image is in a public accessible URL, from where Twilio can retrieve the image and embedd.

Comment: Please add twilio to the tags so twilio experts can find this issue for help

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the Media Url feature of twilio, your image must be placed where twilio api can access without authentication or authorization.

The error message indicates that twilio is unable to download your image from the source.

Try to provide a public available image url from google search and see if it works then ur image should be in a public folder similar to that.

Comment: The url is a publicly shared link from onedrive.  If I provide the URL to someone outside my organization, they can click on it and access the picture, so I would THINK twilio should be able to.    I could move it to a google drive instead, but then power automate never plays nice with google.

Comment: Did you try to give any image thats public available? Like website branding images?